# Invalid Object name error but table found in schema?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, adodb

I'm using ADODB connections to connect to a database which none of my other colleagues understand how to connect to. So far I've got as far as being able to see all the available tables via 2 methods:

```
Dim ado as object
set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Call ado.open("...")

set rs = ado.Execute("SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type='U'")
```

and also

```
const adTable = 20
Set rstSchema = ado.OpenSchema(adTable)
Do Until rstSchema.EOF
    Debug.Print rstSchema("TABLE_NAME")
    rstSchema.MoveNext
Loop
```

But the part which is confusing me is selecting from the tables directly... I expected to be able to do:

```
select * from <<TABLENAME>>
```

where `<<TABLENAME>>` was one of the table names returned by the above 2 methods. However whenever I do this I get the error in the title:

```
Invalid object name '<<TABLENAME>>'.
```

So how exactly am I meant to access the data in the tables identified from OpenSchema() method. Is there another method which I am unfamiliar with?

Comment: Seconds after posting the question I tried (what appears to be) `<<Catalog>>.<<Schema>>.<<TableName>>`. Can anyone confirm this is the proper name to use?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: @DaveInCaz I believe it's SQL Server

Comment: When doing a SELECT * FROM TableName, the TableName has to be an explicit table name... it cannot be a variable.  You can build a string of SQL from the results, so that you end up passing the SQL as a string, where it's explicitly stating the full SQL statement, passing to an EXECUTE statement to execute, and then read back the results. But you cannot parameterize the table name.

Comment: Confirmed. In SQL Server terms: `<<Database>>.<<Owner>>.<<TableName>>`. You can just use <<TableName>> if first you execute `USE <<Database>>`. Then suddenly Owner is no longer important.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed with itsLex in the comments:

In SQL Server terms:

```
select * from <<Database>>.<<Owner>>.<<TableName>>
```

Alternatively you can use the `USE` statement as follows:

```
USE <<Database>>;
select * from <<TableName>>;
```